# Creating a variable by adding another variable and an integer

Tags: ruby

I’m trying to create a simple program in Ruby to learn from. It asks you for a number. It takes that number, adds 1 to it, and tells you this new number is a better number.

```
puts ‘hello, what is your favorite number?
fav = gets.to_i
puts fav + 1 ‘would be a better choice!’
```

If I eliminate ‘would be a better choice!’ or put that on it’s own line, this works fine. I can’t figure out what I’m doing wrong on this.

Thank you for any help sorting this out.

Comment: A hint here is that you had to add 1 to `fav` to create a new number, now you are trying to add that number to the front of the string `'would be a better choice!'`

Comment: `fav` , `1` and `"would be a better choice!"` are all objects, not all of them are the same type of object and you can't just write one object after another without any additional operation and expect ruby to figure out what to do :) should help you out figure the issue out on your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code:

```
puts ‘hello, what is your favorite number?
fav = gets.to_i
puts fav + 1 ‘would be a better choice!’
```

The first thing that's off is the missing closing quote in the first row. The next thing that should be changed and is causing the error is this

```
fav + 1 'would be a better chocice!'
```

`fav` is an int, so is `1` so that's ok, but just writing a string after that is going to cause an error. So we need to tell Ruby we want to combine the int and the string and we do that with the plus sign (`+`). But trying to combine an int with a string is going to cause an `String can't be coerced into Integer` error. So we need to somehow transform the int into a string. And we do that using the `#to_s` method which will return the string representation of that integer which brings us to:

```
puts 'hello, what is your favorite number?'
fav = gets.to_i
puts (fav + 1).to_s + ' would be a better choice!'
```

However, changing the last line to use string interpolation:

```
puts "#{fav + 1} would be a better choice!"
```

Would be (as Chris said in the comment section) the idiomatic Ruby way to do this.

I would also recommend you to look at Ruby's wiki tag and check out all the available resources on Ruby as they will give you a better learning curve now than just practicing random methods and stuff on your own. Good luck!

Comment: "is the missing closing bracket in the first row" - it's a quote, not a bracket or apostrophe :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I noticed that as I read the answer again, thank you!

Comment: I get the logical progression of your answer, but I feel you should mention that the idiomatic ruby way to do this would be with string interpolation: `puts "#{fav + 1} would be a better choice!"`

Comment: @ChrisHall I thought about doing that, but I was afraid that adding that would require an explanation of the syntax which would just further derive the answer from the original question. But as this has turned into a beginner's Ruby lesson anyway, I see no reason not to add it. Thank you for you input!

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I’m working through Chris Pine’s “Learn to Program” and this was one of the programs to try on your own. I guess a shortcoming of the book is there’s not an example in the back of the book if you get stuck. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

This should work as expected:

```
puts "hello, what is your favorite number?"
fav = gets.to_i
puts "#{fav + 1} would be a better choice!"
```